# When to use "Only thing" vs. "Everything"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Here are 2 examples that I think both make sense. I am confused about them.

> It is not waterproof. That is everything that is bad about it.
>
> It is not waterproof. That is the only thing that is bad about it.

I think 'every' makes sense in this case because it covers all of the things that are bad about it, which is one. In other words, it is like

```
That is everything; that is it.
```

Which is correct? Do they have different meanings? When should I use one or the other? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your reasons why you think _everything_ might be acceptable?  Have you found a definition of _everything_ that seems like it might work to refer to a single item?  Note that _every thing_ is not exactly the same as _everything._

Comment: It sounds sensible to me too @Adam. Hmm, is this a common "learner confusion"?

Comment: @MARamezani - Are you saying my comment is sensible, or his question, or something else?

Comment: I meant *it*. That *it* in the question. :) I meant the OP's first statement which s\he considers plausible while a native doesn't. (The one with *everything, and this is a pun)

Answer (score 4):

- *It is not waterproof. That is the **only** thing that is bad about it.*

This is the most natural sounding phrase.  There is only one thing that is bad about it.  You state the bad thing, and reiterate that it stands alone as being a fault.

- *It is not waterproof. That is **everything** that is bad about it.*

*Everything* means all of the things of a group - it refers to the collection, and the collection normally has more than one item within it.  While it isn't horribly wrong, and would be understood, I would not use this.

- *Every thing* vs. *everything*

*Every thing*  highlights each of the things as it's own entity, rather than as a collective.  Imagine if I said *Make sure every thing is put away.*  I am acknowledging that different things have different repositories, and asking for the listener to exercise care that **each** item is treated with care.  999 of the 1000 items being stowed, is NOT *every thing.*

Contrast with *Make sure everything is put away.*  Now I am not focusing on these objects as separate things. As a collection, I want them put where they go.  And if I put away 48 of the 50 things that were out, I might be OK saying I put away *everything.*

I can picture a circumstance where I would use **every thing** in your phrase.

> A: Tell me everything that is wrong with this backpack.
>
> B: It isn't waterproof.
>
> A: I asked you to tell me everything that is wrong with it.
>
> B: "That *is* **every** thing."

---

That is everything I have to say about this.

Comment: I guess that wasn't _every_ thing:  I would use "wrong with" rather than "bad about."  _It is not waterproof. That is the only thing wrong with it._